# how to display data in ascending order of a text file c#

Tags: c#, arrays, text-files

i need to sort and display my code by ascending order based off on the item number. Here's the sample code.

```
string data = $"{itemNumber}|{itemName}|{itemPrice}";

using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("items.txt"))
{
    writer.WriteLine(data);
}

public void DisplayItemList()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("items.txt"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n ---------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(" Item No.     Item Name      Price");
        Console.WriteLine(" ---------------------------------");

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            string[] fields = line.Split('|');
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" {0,-13}{1,-16}{2,0}", fields[0], fields[1], fields[2]));
        }

        Console.Write("\n");
    }
}
```

here's my sample code. as you can see i have

```
1 - oslopaper | 34 - bond | 11 - art
```

I needed it to be

```
1 - oslopaper, 11 - art, lastly, 34 - bond
```

because I wanted it to be in ascending order.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *querying* file with a help of *Linq* (here you can add ordering - `OrderBy`; representing - `Select`, headers - `Prepend`):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

...

public void DisplayItemList() {
  var result = File
    .ReadLines("items.txt")
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // to be on the safer side
    .Select(line => line.Split('|'))
    .OrderBy(fields => int.Parse(fields[0]))
    .Select(fields => $" {fields[0],-13}{fields[1],-16}{fields[2],0}")
    .Prepend(" --------------------------------- ")
    .Prepend(" Item No.     Item Name      Price ")
    .Prepend(" --------------------------------- ");

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sort items before displaying them by LINQ

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("items.txt")
                .OrderBy(line => int.Parse(line.Split('|')[0]));
```